# Flask-SQLAlchemy - how to order a query object list?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some files and info about them is in a SQL db. For a given group of files, they will all share a common gallery_id(text) and different upload_time(datetime). I'm trying to get a list of files that all share a common gallery id and then sort them by upload_time, but it isn't working. This is the syntax I used:

```
    >>> foo = Storedfile.query.filter_by(
        gallery_id ='kgLivY').all().order_by(Storedfile.upload_time)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do the `.all()` last.

```
foo = Storedfile.query.filter_by(
    gallery_id='kgLivY').order_by(
        Storedfile.upload_time
    ).all()
```

`all()` returns a standard python `list` which then doesn't have the attribute/method `order_by`.